# Is EGit compatible with Eclipse Galileo and Eclipse Helios?

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

We have a product based on Eclipse. Today we support differents versions of our product: one is base on Eclipse 3.5 and another is based on Eclipse 3.6. Now, we would like to provide the EGit plugins within our product.

I've found the following comment on the EGit FAQ (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ)
"EGit 0.7.1 requires Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) or newer".

So, my questions are:

- What is the compatibility of EGit 0.11.3 with Eclipse versions ?
- Is EGit officially supported for Eclipse 3.6 ? With Eclipse 3.5 ?
- Have someone already delivered it successfully in an Helios based product ?

Regards,
Jerome

Comment: I can vouch that it works fine in Helios.

Answer (score 1):

- The p2 metadata of egit 0.11.3 indicates that it should run with Eclipse 3.5
- The [marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider) says Eclipse 3.5.2 is required
- EGit was part of the Helios simultanious release, but with version 0.8

If you need an official answer for what Eclipse versions the egit team wants to support in the future, you should read the answer to [your question in the egit forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=207549&start=0&S=6bd415d1b9fcaaf94f67e0552c3dac00).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it runs on Eclipse 3.5. It has been hacked by others to run on Eclipse 3.4 as well, though this isn't officially supported. Other commercial products based on Eclipse 3.5 also include EGit; you can install subsequent newer ones with the EGit release site.